# Active Admin Rails4 custom filter with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, ransack

I've the resource Order. In my admin panel (activeadmin) I need a boolean filter to get all orders where the user have a specific role.

In the Order class I've a scope like this:

```
class Order
  belongs_to :user
  scope :client_only_in, -> { joins(:user).where('users.role = ?', 'client') }
end
```

In active admin order.rb I've add the follow filter:

```
filter :client_only, as: :check_boxes
```

With rails 3 (metasearch) I can add

```
search_method :client_only_in, type: :boolean
```

to get the filter, but with rails 4 and Ransack I dont know how to do this.

Without adding the `search_method` to the order model I get the error

```
undefined method `client_only_in' for Ransack::Search
```

when I visit index admin orders page.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do exactly this, but you can always have a select field to filter based on User roles:

```
filter :users_role, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: proc{ User.uniq.pluck :role }
```

UPDATE: Ah, if an Order `belongs_to` a User than it should be `:user_role` instead of `:users_role`